# How can i add from transform.position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add transform.position.z an unit every keydown

```
void Update()
{
    positionZ = transform.position.z + count; //The problem with this line is unity plus 'count' every frame, not once per key
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)){
        count++;
    }
    float step =  speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(0,1,count), step);

}
```

This works perfectly, adds one unit to Z, but I want to add **from** transform.position, so if i do

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(0,1,positionZ), step);
```

This will plus every frame, not once per keydown. I tried to put

```
positionZ = transform.position.z + count;
```

outside of Update but it doesn't work. Please help, i'm beginner
Pd: I tried

```
count = transform.position.z;
count++;
```

but doesn't add correctly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Update()
{
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)){
        
       float speed = 1f;
       transform.position += Vector3.forward * speed;

    }

}
```

here try :)

Comment: With this code there is no "smooth" transition, but instantaneous. Anyway, thank you for your time ♥